# BLASTN in NCBI strand Plus/Minus

Tags: bioinformatics

I am a newbie in Bioinformatics. I am trying to understand terminologies used in NCBI BLAST system. Here is what I am trying to align:

[image]

So effectively I am trying to align two sequences with the following property.

[image]

So the query is part of reverse complement of the subject sequence. Now BLAST is throwing me the following result:

[image]

My confusion here is with the numbering system with query sequence starts from 1 from left side whereas the subject sequence starts from 1 from right side. Now I am assuming the numbering system starts from $5'$ end of any sequence and from the handwritten note above, it is clear that to align these two sequences I have to further reverse the subject string so that the $5'$ end of both sequences match up and hence numbering for both sequences should start from left side as opposed to what is presented in BLAST result page. BUT, I am suspecting that in my handwritten note in the reverse complement of subject sequence I have mentioned the $3'$ end in left side as is the case in DNA. But if I just take the (non - reverse) complement of the subject sequence keeping the $5'$ end towards left side, then and only then the numbering system works. But why we want to take complement of a given nucleotide sequence in non-reverse way!

Can someone kindly throw some light on this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, BLAST is making a *best alignment*, which is to the complement of your ‘Subject sequence’. That is how BLAST works, especially as other subject sequences may be genomes with genes oriented in different directions. And BLAST seems to be assuming that the numbering of your ‘Subject sequence’ is ‘official’ in some way (as it would be if it had been deposited in a data bank), and hence retaining it.

But as a “newbie in Bioinformatics” you should consult a suitable book and read about pairwise sequence alignment — which is what you appear to be attempting. An implementation of the [Smith–Waterman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm), such as [that on the EBI site](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/jdispatcher/psa/emboss_water), would seem more appropriate. This gives the alignment of the strands you entered:

```
EMBOSS_001         1 ATTGGCATT      9
                     |.||.||.|
EMBOSS_001         1 AATGCCAAT      9
```

If you want to check both strands, you need to do the reverse complementation yourself here.

There is also an EBI implementation available for the Needleman and Wunsch algorithm for global sequence alignment.